# I want to skip warnings in PMD

Tags: pmd

I get the following when I run the `PMD Report` in my `target/pmd.xml` using teamcity

Now I wanted to skip the following warnings  `"Unused Code"` . So how can I do that ?

Presently the build is failing , when I googled I got one option where I can use the

Annotation `@Suppress warnings`   (But I wanted to skip these warnings from my maven goals

itself , is there any goal like  skip warnings?   or something like that)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pmd version="5.0.2" timestamp="2014-04-07T07:41:55.431">
<file name="/home/herc/teamcity/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/c2f0847f19a6b00d/src/main/java/com/ga/gameon/db/IapDAO.java">
<violation beginline="16" endline="16" begincolumn="16" endcolumn="61" rule="UnusedModifier" ruleset="Unused Code" package="com.ga.gameon.db" class="IapDAO" externalInfoUrl="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0$
Avoid modifiers which are implied by the context
</violation>
<violation beginline="17" endline="17" begincolumn="16" endcolumn="56" rule="UnusedModifier" ruleset="Unused Code" package="com.ga.gameon.db" class="IapDAO" externalInfoUrl="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0$
Avoid modifiers which are implied by the context
</violation>
</file>
<file name="/home/herc/teamcity/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/c2f0847f19a6b00d/src/main/java/com/ga/gameon/service/IapService.java">
<violation beginline="18" endline="18" begincolumn="16" endcolumn="83" rule="UnusedModifier" ruleset="Unused Code" package="com.ga.gameon.service" class="IapService" externalInfoUrl="http://pmd.sourceforge.ne$
Avoid modifiers which are implied by the context
</violation>
<violation beginline="20" endline="20" begincolumn="16" endcolumn="76" rule="UnusedModifier" ruleset="Unused Code" package="com.ga.gameon.service" class="IapService" externalInfoUrl="http://pmd.sourceforge.ne$
Avoid modifiers which are implied by the context
</violation>
</file>
<file name="/home/herc/teamcity/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/c2f0847f19a6b00d/src/main/java/com/ga/gameon/service/IapServiceImpl.java">

</file>
</pmd>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider simply removing unneeded rules from your *pmd.xml*. For example, if you don't want "unused modifiers" to be flagged, remove the "Unused Modifier" rule.

If you only want to suppress specific occurrences, you can specify suppressions in your *pmd.xml* as [documented here](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.0/suppressing.html#Violation_Suppress_Regex).

For example, to suppress reporting specifically named parameters which are unused:

```xml
<rule ref="rulesets/unusedcode.xml/UnusedFormalParameter">
    <property name="violationSuppressRegex" value=".*'mySpecialParamName'.*"/>
</rule>
```

Comment: I used exactly the following in my pom file                           < rule ref="rulesets/unusedcode.xml/UnusedFormalParameter">
    <property name="violationSuppressRegex" value=".*'mySpecialParamName'.*"/>
</rule>

Comment: < rule ref="rulesets/unusedcode.xml/UnusedFormalParameter"> <property name="violationSuppressRegex" value=".*'UselessParentheses'.*"/> </rule>   - I tried using the above syntax  its not working . Can you please suggest me whether this is correct or not . The above syntax is not working

Comment: Did you try to *remove* the unwanted rule? That would be easiest. Also remember that the regex is applied to the *message text*, not the rule name or something.

Comment: How do I remove unwanted rule ? please tell me

Comment: could you please tell me the regex as well . Suppose I wanted to exclude the rule  name  Uselesss parenthesis . is the format correct     value=".*'UselessParentheses'.*" ????

Comment: *How do I remove unwanted rule?* - Well, just select the XML element and press the *Delete* key in your text editor!

Comment: The fact that you are suggesting `UselessParentheses` as part of the regex leads me to assume that what you really want to do is suppress the entire rule. That should be done by removing it from the pmd.xml.